# How do I split an SQL column that is part string part number with variable length

Tags: sql, string, split, integer

I have an ID column that uses letters and numbers: `A00055` or `AI000075` for example.
The text values are in ascending order by ASCII code so I was going to do something like this:

```
CAST((COALESCE(ASCII(SUBSTRING([FaultID],1,1)),SUBSTRING([FaultID],2,(len([FaultID])))))AS bigint) as FaultID1
```

However then I realized that the letters can be of variable length 1-3 characters in length so this errors out as soon as I hit a value with 2 letters. Is there a way to split the string on the first numeric value? Or is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use the PATINDEX (pattern index), instead of the CHARINDEX.

`SELECT PATINDEX('%[0-9]%','MyString1111')`

This will return a 1-based index of the first numeric value in the string, which you can then use to split the string.

Documentation for PATINDEX is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).